# TextToSpeech initialization listener fires but the TTS engine is not initialized

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm creating an app which uses the TextToSpeech class. I'm having an issue with the initialization (my device is a Android Nougat Nexus 5X).

My code is very simple :

- My activity contains a `private TextToSpeech tts;` field
- The `onCreate` method initialized the TTS like so : `tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);`
- In my activity I implement the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` interface
- The `onInit` method contains a check if the status is a success, if so shows a debug Toast and tries to speak

The expected result is that once the TTS engine is initialized, it will show my debug Toast and speak afterwards.

What I got is different : the `onInit` method is called almost immediately, my Toast is shown and... nothing. After a solid 10-15s delay, I can hear my lovely phone speak.

Isn't the `onInit` event supposed to be fired when the TTS engine is ready to speak ? Why is the method called immediately without waiting for the TTS engine to be ready ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in Google's TTS Engine. I tried to use PicoTTS, and it works well.

Comment: You're right but Pico TTS is not as good as Google's. Samsung's works like a charm too.

Comment: @natinusala And I'm not sure, is it possible to fix it with code. Google should fix this in their engine.

Comment: I guess they should but I would need a good TTS engine for my app and I won't wait for Google to notice and fix this issue on their own. I need to find another free engine

Comment: @natinusala have you gotten this to work? I am having trouble with TTS engine initialized. I keep getting TextToSpeech.ERROR = -1 and onInit status is always -1.